# Using lookup transformation for 2 columns at the same time

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I want to use lookup transformation for 2 columns at the same time in SSIS. For example, if there are 3 columns ProductID,CreatedDate,Pname I need to compare 2 columns say ProductID and CreatedDate at the same time so that only if a row has same ProductID but different Created Date it should go in no match output. Currently my transformation is just using productid and if its already exists, it is putting in matched rows even after having a different CreatedDate.

[image]

As per above example, both ProductID with 1 should be there in no match output.

How can we implement this in SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Currently I believe you have only `source.ProducID` mapped to `destination.ProductID` in lookup.

All you need to do is map `source.CreatedDate` to `destination.CreatedDate`.

You need to do something like this :

[image: img]

Comment: It doesn't show in no match output. It still shows in matched output.

Comment: @Shivang : Can you post the screenshots of your lookup and data flow ?